# Mapbox GL JS with Directions. Disable setOrigin and setDestination on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using Mapbox GL JS with directions.

The default behavior for the directions feature is that it sets an origin and a destination for the directions where you click when you click on the map layer. I want to disable this feature.

How do I do so? What I'm doing now doesn't work.

```
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.4.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.4.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />

    <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-directions/v4.1.0/mapbox-gl-directions.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-directions/v4.1.0/mapbox-gl-directions.css" type="text/css">    
   
    <div id='map'></div> 

    <script>    
        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'token';
    
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            center: [76, -122],
            zoom: 12
        });
    
        var directions = new MapboxDirections({
            accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken
        });
    
        map.addControl(directions,'top-right');

        //Disable "onclick" directions
        map.directions.on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        map.on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        directions.on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an `interactive` option in the `MapboxDirections` constructor which you can set to `false`:

```
    var directions = new MapboxDirections({
        accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
        interactive: false
    });
```

See the API documentation here: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/blob/master/API.md#mapboxdirections